# How can I make sure a user does not input an unwanted letter or word into a variable which undergoes the eval function?

Tags: python, eval, jupyter

Say I input the letter g into this code, the error, g is not defined will 
occur. I imagine this is due to the fact I am using the eval function. Is 
there any way of getting around this or is there another way of making sure a letter or word is not inputted into the code.

```
    c = eval(input("Input sin(radians(your angle))"))
    B = isinstance(c, (int, float, complex))
    if B == False:
        print ("This is not a valid input, the input must be a number")
        c = eval(input("Input sin(radians(your angle))"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `eval()`.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('42')
42
>>> ast.literal_eval('3.14')
3.14
>>> ast.literal_eval('4-2j')
(4-2j)
>>> ast.literal_eval('os.system("rm -rf /")')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f8a8e4ae978>
```